# 2-way set associative mapping Hit or Miss

Tags: cpu-cache

I've been trying to find out how to determine Hit or Miss regarding this info:
2-Way Set associative cache memory which contains 32 blocks with 4 bytes in each block,
Accesses were done to addresses no 7,13,37,27,33,11,7,18,34,23.

I know how to determine Hit or Miss in direct-mapped cache but it seems irrelevant in K-Way Set associative cache. I would be thankful for any help as I didn't find proper explanation on the web.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that hit and miss is irrelevant in case of set associative cache?